# problem with install, uninstall ,and upgrade packages on pip

Tags: python, pip, package, site-packages

whenever I want to update/upgrade packages with pip I see the following message:

**WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)**

and when I go to the mentioned path I see folders like **~rgcomplete-1.12.2.dist-info** that contain some files that I don't know what to do. please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with a folder name under `c:\python39\lib\site-packages`.

Since I don't know the contents I can't find what is wrong but deleting folders that contain characters like ~ should work.